# google is ranking the wrong url for my keywords

Tags: seo, google, keywords

I have a food blog and I publish recipes. Recently, Google is ranking my posts with the wrong URL for the majority of the content.

[image: semrush ranking]

It's linking the homepage for my keywords. I already submitted my sitemap in the search console (I thought it was a sitemap problem) -> sitemap but I got `unknown sitemap` in the search console:

[image: sitemap]

I don't know if it's a sitemap or an internal linking problem, I added internal links to the concerned page. I don't know what makes google rank the wrong urls. Is it a Google crawl problem? any help would be appreciated

What I tried: I added the sitemap to robots.txt

[image: robots.txt]

I tried internal links to the concerned posts and posted my sitemap to google search console